# difference between looping a cursor and looping cursor.fetchall in row queries

Tags: django

Let's say I have following code

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
```

after that point I want to loop over all the resultset.

what is the difference between

```
for row in cursor:
    print row[0]


for row in cursor.fetchall():
   print row[0]

I
```

am guessing that first one is using fetchone method.

1) Is first one runs a query on every iteration. 
2) does it use fetchone method or fetchall method
3) which is better for big resultset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ability to iterate over a cursor is an optional extension as defined by [PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), and the exact semantics depend upon the database adapter being used.

Comment: I checked this with debugsqlshell and it seems like it runs the query in cursor.execute method. ( tried it on postgresql)